# What is the difference between a waypoint and a significant point in an airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airspace, aeronautical-charts, airways, aeronautical-information

I know ATS routes are made up of *waypoints*, but what are *Significant Points* used for? Is there a difference, or are they really just two names for the same thing?

Comment: Never heard of that term. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is perfectly clear. It is asking about the difference between two commonly used and very similar terms.

Comment: @MichaelHall Significant Point is a defined term. https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Significant_Point

Comment: @MichaelHall Example: https://aim.naviair.dk/media/files/213fmv0yw3h/EK_ENR_4_4_en.pdf

Comment: @MichaelHall No one said anything about the FAA. Not sure why it matters if it's an FAA term or not.

Comment: @MichaelHall nobody confirmed that Significant Point it is not an FAA term. expeditedescent just pointed to a definition. The original source is actually ICAO Annex 11. The USA is an ICAO member, so within the FAA the term Significant Point is probably used as well.

Comment: @MichaelHall I can now confirm that the FAA uses the term as well, with a slightly different definition.

Comment: @DeltaLima, yep, I found it in the FAA glossary.  Definitions are virtually identical.  I’m still hoping an answer will provide some context because I haven’t heard the term actually used before.

Comment: @RalphJ I was reading an EAIP of Singapore and saw it there. It seems Significant points are not a part of the documented air route but a pilot can still be asked to maneuver to or from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ICAO PANS-ATM (Doc 4444) 16th Edition,

Waypoint is a type of significant point.

Mentioned in Chapter 1 - Definition as

> **Significant point** :- A specified geographical location used in defining an ATS route or the flight path of an aircraft and for other
> navigation and ATS purposes.  *Note.— There are three categories of
> significant points: ground-based navigation aid, intersection and
> waypoint. In the context of this definition, intersection is a
> significant point expressed as radials, bearings and/or distances from
> ground-based navigation aids.*
>
> **Waypoint** is defined as a specified geographical location used to define an area navigation route or the flight path of an aircraft
> employing area navigation.

So in short waypoint is a significant point used to define an area navigation route or the flight path of an aircraft employing area navigation

Comment: This is the book definition, but they sound very similar to me.  The OP asked "are they really just two names for the same thing?" It would appear to me that they are.  Can you offer a practical example of how they might be used differently?  It would help to have some context.

Comment: A VOR reporting point on a conventional ATS route (Non RNAV ) is a significant point but  not a waypoint if it is flown by an aircraft not employing area navigation.

Comment: it is a waypoint if you put it in your flight plan and fly to it.  I have never heard anybody ever refer to a point on their flight plan as a “significant point”.  In normal use, if it is in your route of flight it is commonly referred to as a waypoint, fix, intersection, turn point, or NTP, (Nav Turn Point). This is of course based solely on personal experience, so I cannot make any claim beyond 4 decades of flying, mainly in the US.  Other country’s pilots may very well use the term “significant” in normal conversation.

Comment: The question was about the difference between these two terms. It doesn't matter whether pilots uses this term in normal conversations. ICAO PANS-ATM uses 'significant point' term whenever the rules or separations are based on either a waypoint or a nav-aid. A nav-aid becomes a waypoint only when you put the nav-aid coordinates in FMS and fly. If an aircraft without FMS  onboard flying by tuning in to  a VOR onboard, then  it's a significant point and not a waypoint and separations methods  mentioned in PANS-ATM for aircraft employing area navigation may not be applied between such aircraft.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Sounds like it is more relevant to ATC then.  Perhaps you could add this information to the answer?  And I assume that you provide the different separation based on the equipment code?

Comment: @Michael Hall. Separation methods and minima  depends upon the navigational aid and  capability of aircraft especially in non-radar environment. ATC gets alerts and warning from automation systems when an aircraft is not equipped with right equipments for the airspace they are flying. An aircraft having no GPS / VOR board cannot be separated using VOR lateral separation minima mentioned in PANS-ATM even though it is difficult to find an aircraft in such a condition. So there comes the importance of significant points and waypoint.